# C++ Code Output explanation

Tags: c++, loops, pointers, for-loop, output

I have the following code, and the question asks me to find the output. I've found the output (2) by typing it in, but I'm having trouble figuring out how/why. Any Help?

Here's the code:

```
int scores[5];
int *numbers = scores;
for (int i=0; i <=4; i++)
  *(numbers+i)=i;
cout << numbers[2] <<endl;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code essentially does

```
scores[2] = 2;
cout<<scores[2]<<endl;
```

Thus the answer..

In more detail:

```
int scores[5];
int *numbers = scores;  //numbers points to the memory location of the array scores
for (int i=0; i <=4; i++) // as mentioned, stray ';'
  *(numbers+i)=i; //same as numbers[i] = i  which is same as scores[i] = i
cout << numbers[2] <<endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

The only statement being executed by the for loop is

```
*(numbers+i)=i;
```

Which will store the index of the int element at that position using the deference operator (*).

Then you are printing out the THIRD number, which equates to 2, since arrays start at index 0.

Answer (score 0):

You set a pointer to the first memory location of the array, then traverse the series of memory addresses and write to them. It should be noted that using pointer arithmetic with a dereference,

```
*(pointer + i) = i;
```

is the same as using the subscript operator:

```
pointer[i] = i;
```